# Выделение ListView Item по условию

Tags: java, android, listview, getview

Здравствуйте. Имеется кастомный array адаптер.В `getView()` подсвечиваю нужный Item

```
if (index == data[position])
convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
else
convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Но при таком подходе, если я просто кликаю по item, то не работает selected

Решил использовать `setSelected()`

```
if (index == data[position])
convertView.setSelected(true);
else
convertView.setSelected(false);
```

Но item отказывается выделятся.Ставил отладочные сообщения с isSelected.Так на нужном item получал как будто он выделен, но визуально нет.

По событию `OnItemClickListener`

```
if (index == data[position])
convertView.setSelected(true);
else
convertView.setSelected(false);
```

Все выделяется.Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Почему `setSelected()` в `OnItemClickListener` работает, а в `getView()` работает, но не выделяется? Как это решить.Нужно что бы по нажатию на item мелькнуло выделение и item выделился.

getView

> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>           ViewHolder holder;

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = this._layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        if (index == data[position]) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            //convertView.setSelected(true);
        } else
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        //convertView.setSelected(false);

    holder.name.setText(data[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста код метода getView()

Comment: Если нужно выложу но там все просто.Там получаю виджеты разметки и собственно это условие по выделению.В OnItemClickListener обнавляю запись в БД и тут же пытаюсь подсветить нажатый item.

Comment: Выложите, чтобы наглядно видеть что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Добавил смотрите

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать селектор `lvBg.xml` для `ListView` в `drawable`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

в res/value/colors:

```
<color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
<color name="default_color">#ffffff</color>
```

И применить `background` для `ListView`

```
android:background="@drawable/lvBg"
```

Если не получится, то попробуйте этот [метод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33183271/5797206),  должно помочь